# Именованная группа в строке замены регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Доброго времени суток. 
Есть выражение

```
/(?P<name>[0-9]+)/
```

Оно создает именованную ссылку с именем name, но как использовать это в строке замены? То есть хотелось бы нечто вроде

```
preg_replace($re, "\{name}", $text);
```

Вариант с `\1` не предлагать.
В Perl этот эффект достигается таким путем:

```
s/(?P<name>[0-9]+)/$+{name}/
```

но `$+` это конструкция самого языка, а не регулярных выражений.
Как достичь этого в PHP?
**Добавлено**
Методом тыка пробовал варианты:

```
\{name}
\\{name}
\k{name}
\g{name}
${name}
$name
$+{name}
%+{name}
```

Нужен аналог $+ в вариации PHP.

Comment: Задал этот же вопрос на [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680913/php-named-groups-in-the-replacement-string).  
Видимо гугль переводчик что-то не так напереводил :)

Comment: поставил + на SO, по-братски, а то заминусовали тебя там...

Comment: @johniek_comp, спасибо :) Я в английском не ахти. По этой теме весь гугл порвал- ничего не нашел. Придется наверно Release Notes к PCRE и preg_* курить :(

Answer (score 1):

[Регулярные выражения PCRE. Обратные ссылки.](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.back-references.php)

> Указать обратную ссылку на именованную подмаску можно с помощью `(?P=name)` или, начиная с PHP 5.2.2, `\k<name>` или `\k'name'`. Кроме того, в PHP 5.2.4 была добавлена поддержка `\k{name}` и `\g{name}`.

PS Поиск ответа стоит всегда начинать с официальной документации.

Comment: Неверно к сожалению. В выражении замены это не работает.

Comment: Ну в таком случае, ответ - никак.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Синтаксис в строке замены - $name

```
echo preg_replace('/(xyi)/', "тут было написано '$1'", "str");
```

Comment: Неверно. Вы неправильно поняли вопрос.